# Ignore whitespace while reading XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML format with following format

```
<Tag>
    Value
</Tag>
```

This comes from an external datasource I cannot change.
When using `XmlReader` the content has `Linebreaks` and `Whitepace`.

```
XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlSettings.Schemas = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet();
XmlReader schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(xsdStream);
xmlSettings.Schemas.Add("", schemaReader);
xmlSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilename, xmlSettings);
// Parse the XML file.
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.IsStartElement())
    {
         switch (reader.Name)
         {
             case "Tag":
                 string value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                 Console.WriteLine(value);
                 break; 
          }
     }
}
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Any reason not to use `value.Trim()`? And do you really need to use `XmlReader` instead of LINQ to XML or similar? (Unless you're reading a huge document, it's *much* simpler to parse the whole thing into a DOM first.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not working answer**

This answer doesn't seem to work, but I'm leaving it for the moment to avoid anyone else suggesting it. I'll delete this if someone posts a better answer.

Did you try setting [`XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.ignorewhitespace.aspx)?

> White space that is not considered to be significant includes spaces, tabs, and blank lines used to set apart the markup for greater readability. An example of this is white space in element content.

For some reason this *doesn't* affect `ReadElementContentAsString` or even the `Value` property of a text node.

**Simple answer**

You could just call `Trim`:

```
string value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString().Trim();
```

That won't remove line breaks *between* contentful lines, of course... if you need to do that, you could always use `string.Replace`.

(As I mentioned in the comment, I'd personally prefer using LINQ to XML than `XmlReader` unless you're genuinely reading something too large to fit in memory, but that's a separate matter.)

Comment: `XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace` only affects text nodes that consist solely of whitespace. In this case `<Tag>` contains the text node "\r\n····Value\r\n".

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. I personally would also like to switch to LINQ, but my project needs to build with `.net 2.0`.

Comment: @Razer: You could still use `XmlDocument` which would be easier to use than `XmlReader` - at least, I certainly find it easier.